# Nome de pessoas devem ser armazenados em duas ou apenas uma coluna?

Tags: modelagem, ux

Em sistemas de negócios, especialmente ERPs internacionais ou mesmo em cadastros em *sites* vemos que o cadastro pede o sobrenome (*last name*) e o nome (*first name*). Em alguns casos há até o nome do meio (*middle name*).

No Brasil eu não me lembro de ter visto isto em algum lugar. Sempre é usado uma coluna de nome único sem separação das partes.

#### Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um do ponto de vista de modelagem e experiência do usuário?

*Bonus point* (não é o foco principal da pergunta e não sei se pode ser respondido de forma autoritativa):

Por que isto ocorre por aqui? Seria uma questão cultural histórica?

Note que é uma questão de modelagem de dados e também de experiência do usuário. nem sempre eles se compatibilizam diretamente.

Uma [referência sobre o assunto](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names).

Comment: Em alguns sites, eles até perguntam com qual pronome de tratamento o usuário/pessoa prefere ser chamado (Mr., Mrs., Miss, Ms , Sir.). E talvez seja por isso que eles separam o nome do sobrenome..  Sir Oliveira, Mr. Silva

Comment: @emanuelsn De fato este é um motivo comum para se obter o sobrenome separado. Em inglês formal, o título "Mr." é utilizado apenas com o sobrenome. Outro motivo é a própria apresentação do nome: quando você vai tomar um vôo, o sistema americanizado da companhia aérea o localiza por seu sobrenome e não por seu primeiro nome. O mesmo para sistemas de agenda e CRM americanos em geral. Por fim, nos EUA, na própria convivência social as pessoas se chamam por seu sobrenome quando não íntimos (no Brasil chamamos os amigos pelo sobrenome se o sobrenome tiver uma sonoridade bacana). Legal mas off-topic.

Comment: Tal como qualquer outra informação(dado), a escolha do modo de ela ser armazenada, deve ser equacionada em função de como ela vai ser utilizada.

Comment: Infelizmente esta pergunta está sendo discutida no meta. Neste ponto do *site* já era hora disto não precisar mais: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2412/101

Comment: Imaginando então o caso mais genérico possível (utilizando inclusive referências dos comentários) que seria um ERP internacional como você disse, acho que talvez o requisíto mínimo que consigo imaginar seria pronome, nome, nome do meio, ultimo nome. Isso deve atender a todas as culturas citadas aqui, desde apresentar um "Olá Bruno Silva", até um "Hello Silva, Bruno" ou "Welcome MR Silva". Mas não teria como ser preciso em minha resposta pois não conheço todas as culturas. Prefiro deixar para alguem mais informado responder :o) Boa sorte!

Comment: Eu nunca sei como preencher esses campos. Tenho dois nomes e dois sobrenomes. Qual é o "do meio"? E mesmo que o site não pergunte isso, ao preencher o "Last name" será que eles querem mesmo dois sobrenomes ou querem só o último? Vou eu saber da cultura americana/inglesa/alemã/francesa/portuguesa/chinesa do dono do site??

Comment: @marcus aí é outro problema :)

Comment: @marcus eu sempre fico com essa dúvida ao preencher um formulário em Inglês.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Modelagem

Do ponto de vista de modelagem, essa escolha não parece trazer muita distinção. O espaço ocupado por um ou por outro (seja em memória, em atributos de um objeto, ou em uma tabela em um banco de dados) é praticamente o mesmo. E também não há vantagem alguma em se usar nome ou sobrenome individualmente como identificadores, dado que mesmo o nome completo não é único (homônimos são muito comuns). Mesmo o eventual processamento adicional necessário para concatenar nome e sobrenome para alguma apresentação pode ser igualmente desconsiderado. A dificuldade em separar o sobrenome de um nome em uma única string está mais em se ter certeza a respeito de qual "palavra inteira" forma um sobrenome do que na dificuldade técnica para fazê-lo. Na China, por exemplo, [é mais comum que o nome de família venha à frente do nome dado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_name#Overview).

Talvez seja interessante ter o nome e/ou o sobrenome separado para a criação de índices facilitadores de busca ou aglutinação em relatórios, ou para que o sistema "fale" diretamente ao usuário de maneira formal. Mas essa necessidade depende fortemente do domínio da aplicação. Por exemplo, um sistema de gestão de árvores genealógicas muito provavelmente precisaria ter sobrenomes separados, pois esse dado é uma entidade única por si só, manipulável pelo sistema. Um sistema de venda de passagens aéreas também precisaria fazer essa separação, não por qualquer manipulação interna do sistema mas porque ela precisa ser impressa *corretamente* no bilhete de viagem para que os atendentes possam usar com os passageiros.

### Experiência do Usuário

Assim, parece que essa consideração em manter ou não nome e sobrenome separados advém mais do ponto de vista da experiência do usuário. Quando tais informações são solicitadas geralmente isso se dá por meio de um formulário com campos de texto para a entrada dos dados. Solicitar que o usuário preencha dois (ou mais) desses campos *pode ser* mais desgastante do que solicitar o preenchimento de apenas um.

Considere-se, por exemplo, uma aplicação de entretenimento para ouvir música. O mero fato da aplicação solicitar ao usuário que digite seu nome já pode ser ruim para a experiência, porque o usuário pode se incomodar com:

- o uso que a aplicação fará da informação (questões sobre privacidade), já que a utilidade dessa informação não é aparente ("por que eu preciso fornecer meu nome para ouvir música?")
- (especialmente) a interrupção do seu fluxo de utilização ("poxa, eu queria ouvir uma música, não ficar respondendo perguntas inúteis")

No caso de jogos, por exemplo, a informação de nome pode ter um caráter de utilidade muito aparente para o usuário, como por exemplo ser utilizada para a manutenção de placares (*high scores*). Ainda assim, é completamente desnecessário e disruptivo solicitar separadamente nome e sobrenome. Por isso que, nesses casos, o usuário comumente decide como quer ser chamado (como já bem citado em outras respostas).

### Concluindo

A escolha sobre capturar (e manter) ou não nome e sobrenome separados *depende do domínio da aplicação*, principalmente em relação ao uso que será dado para essa informação separada (critério de usabilidade) e à forma como a informação será solicitada e utilizada com o usuário (critério de experiência do usuário).

Eu já ouvi muitos argumentos do tipo "deixa separado porque, apesar de hoje não precisarmos, amanhã poderemos vir a precisar". Mas a minha experiência indica que isso é bobagem. Primeiramente porque, como sistemas são feitos para pessoas utilizarem, esse tipo de necessidade geralmente é bem visivel aos projetistas logo no início do desenvolvimento. Em segundo lugar porque não é tão difícil extrair automaticamente *sugestões* de sobrenomes de uma base com nomes completo, é claro considerando-se o público-alvo do domínio da aplicação (por exemplo, ela é utilizada no Brasil ou na China?). Ou seja, caso seja necessário, a manutenção de um sistema para que nomes originalmente mantidos em uma única string sejam separados em sobrenomes não é necessariamente difícil, mas a solicitação de sobrenomes separados *desnecessariamente* é provavelmente ruim para a experiência de uso.

Comment: +1. Acho que você poderia destacar o trecho "depende do domínio da aplicação".

Comment: @wryel Feito. Boa sugestão, obrigado. :)

Comment: Discordo um pouco disso pois dependendo da aplicação e do tamanho dela, isso é muito importante sim. O Facebook por exemplo realiza buscas por nome constantemente e com certeza em um volume altíssimo. Se cada parte do nome for colocada em uma única tabela e houver uma estrutura de tabelas n->m com chave composta, não há necessidade de guardar todos os "João". Seria necessário montar uma árvore canônica para fazer os testes, mas tenho certeza que haveria um ganho de desempenho considerável nesse caso. Se uma empresa gasta 100 mil dólares apenas com buscas, 5% de melhora já é excelente.

Comment: @CleitonOliveira Eu não sei se entendi o seu comentário, colega. O que é o "isso" que você discorda e que julga muito importante? Além disso, o seu exemplo parece considerar o nome separado *em tabelas*, mas a pergunta (e a resposta) é a respeito da separação *em colunas*. Realmente, separar em tabelas parece fazer pouco sentido...

Comment: @Luiz o texto como um todo passa uma impressão de falta de necessidade e de ser uma simples questão de gosto, e dependendo do domínio da aplicação havendo talvez uma utilidade. Não é um talvez: levando em conta um volume grande em uma aplicação onde a busca por nome é intensa, é necessária uma avaliação mais profunda, a montagem de casos de uso e otimização de consultas para cada caso para saber o custo computacional delas. Mas claro, sim, é uma questão de gosto e praticidade na grande maioria dos casos.

Comment: @CleitonOliveira Em nenhum momento o texto diz que é "questão de gosto". Essa é uma interpretação sua (e equivocada, eu diria). O texto essencialmente diz que do ponto de vista da modelagem tem pouca diferença, e do ponto de vista da UX pode ter alguma, mas precisa ser avaliado em cada cenário. O "talvez" que aparece diz respeito a uma *eventual* necessidade, específica, de fazer busca por sobrenome. Além disso, eu ainda não entendi a sua questão sobre o desempenho das buscas, já que separado ou não em **colunas de uma mesma tabela** o nome pode ser buscado de forma eficiente.

Answer (score 25):

Em teoria, saber o padrão de nomes da cultura que a maioria dos usuários do seu sistema faz parte irá facilitar bastante as coisas, uma vez que o mesmo terá uma aparência mais próxima à que os mesmos estão acostumados. Mas isso também poderá apresentar desvantagens em diversos casos:

- Se você precisa centralizar os dados de usuários de vários locais (culturas) em um único banco de dados.
- Mesmo dentro de um único país, as pessoas possuem diferentes maneiras de formar nomes pessoais. Por exemplo, podem existir estrangeiros no país ou até diferentes regiões do país seguir culturas diferentes.
- Nem toda cultura possui nomes formados com `Nome + Sobrenome` ou `Nome + Nome da Família`, em muitas culturas nomes podem possuir apenas uma palavra e essa sendo apenas de 2 ou 3 caracteres (por exemplo, An).

### Ok, mas dividir em 2 campos ou não?

Isso você deve se perguntar se realmente precisa ter campos separados para o nome e sobrenome, mas obviamente, será mais simples deixar apenas 1 campo para o usuário. Por isso, **é recomendado que seu sistema seja o mais flexível possível**.

Geralmente, em sistemas profissionais eles utilizam 2 campos para nome e sobrenome para tratar o usuário de maneira formal e precisa, isto é, sem ter que apelar para lógicas que pegam o sobrenome do usuário com base em seu nome completo (que por mais bem estruturadas que sejam, estão sujeitas a falhas).

Por isso, é cada vez mais comum você notar formulários que pedem o seu nome completo em um campo e abaixo, ou em um momento futuro, apresentam a mensagem "**Oi, como você gostaria de ser chamado?**", aí vai do usuário, muitos informam o primeiro nome, outros o sobrenome e alguns outros um apelido mais informal.

Mas respondendo as vantagens e desvantagens de cada abordagem de maneira simples:

- Nome e Sobrenome em 2 campos: proporciona um tratamento por parte do sistema ao usuário mais formal e exato.
- Nome e Sobrenome em 1 campo: permite o usuário inserir seu nome da maneira que ele possa ser, tornando as coisas mais simples e menos trabalhosa.

**O que eu acho** ser uma maneira boa de armazenar o nome completo e mesmo assim ter um tratamento mais pessoal:

- **Nome completo**
  `[__________________________]`
- **Como gostaria de ser chamado?**
  `[________________]` <sub>podendo ser apresentado ao usuário não necessariamente no momento do cadastro.</sub>

---

**Leituras recomendadas:**

[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

[Personal names around the world](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names#fielddesign).

[What's First name and Last name supposed to mean?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66920/whats-first-name-and-last-name-supposed-to-mean).

Answer (score 12):

Depende do modelo de negócios e da cultura local.

Num resumo geral não existe o que é correto. Existe aquilo que é mais adequado.
A decisão de como modelar depende fortemente dos seguintes fatores:

1. Cultural

2. Gramática (pronúncia, fonética)

3. Localidade

4. Modelo de negócios

5. Adaptações a globalização.

Da lista acima, fiz intencionalmente numa ordem de prioridades.

Como já citado em outras respostas, o formato de nomes possui padrões específicos de acordo com a localidade/cultura e idioma.

Muitos no Brasil optam por nome completo num único campo por ser mais prático. Mas mesmo no Brasil é comum modelagens de 3 colunas (nome, sobrenome e nome do meio).

Num país como o Brasil isso é ainda mais confuso pois as pessoas podem ter mais de 3 nomes, sem contar com nomes que possuem partículas (da, do, de) e outras variantes para nomes que indicam que o nome é herdado de um antepassado (filho, neto). Exemplo:

*Maria Conceição da Silva*

*João Vasconcelos Neto*

No caso do João, o nome da família é Vasconcelos. Não existe uma família com nome "Neto".

Nesse caso, como definir o que é o sobrenome e nome do meio para modelagens de 3 colunas?

Isso complica quando os nomes fazem misturas como "*João Vasconcelos Neto da Silva*"

Normalmente prevalece o último nome como sobrenome, mas isso também depende da lógica de negócios da empresa.

Para quem não quer complicações, é mais prático optar por um único campo e fim de conversa. Contudo, a modelagem do sistema ficará presa a uma regra localizada.

Esse mesmo sistema, dificilmente será reaproveitável numa outra localidade como a Ásia, por exemplo.

A fim de tornar mais claro referente a lista de fatores prioritários, segue leitura abaixo:

## Globalização

No Japão as pessoas possuem 2 nomes apenas. Apesar de que isso vem mudando devido a presença de estrangeiros. Mas no geral, um japonês nativo possui apenas nome e sobrenome, sendo que culturalmente o sobrenome deve vir antes do nome.

Há também uma peculiaridade, é comum os formulários pedirem o furigana do nome.
Isso é devido a ideogramas que podem ser difíceis de compreender. Mesmo um japonês nativo pode se confundir ou ter uma interpretação diferente sobre um determinado kanji.

Exemplo: 大道 ー＞ "Daidou". Mas muitos japoneses podem ler como "Oomichi".

<sub>O exemplo aqui não é nome de pessoa. Usei como exemplo para simplificar sobre a importância do furigana nos formulários.</sub>

Por isso, para evitar confusão, principalmente ao atender um cliente pronunciando erroneamente o seu nome, existem mais 2 colunas onde registram-se a versão em furigana.

Exemplo

kanji: 山田太郎

furigana (katakana): ヤマダタロウ

<sub>*Yamada Tarou</sub>

O furigana serve para auxiliar na pronúncia correta do kanji original. Pode ser representado em hiragana ou alfabeto romano. Mas normalmente é em katakana.

Note que a escrita japonesa/chinesa, não possui espaçamento entre as palavras.
Isso dificultaria na abstração de nomes e sobrenomes em modelagens de 1 coluna.

Como culturalmente eles não tem mais de 2 nomes, ficou fácil adotar o padrão de 2 colunas (sobrenome + nome).

Quando um estrangeiro muda-se para o Japão, principalmente estrangeiros do ocidente onde possuem mais de 2 nomes, isso é uma complicação enorme para o governo e empresas adequarem nomes longos e "despadronizados". Aí entra escolha pessoal de cada empresa. Há aqueles que suprimem o nome da pessoa e registram somente o primeiro e último nome e há aqueles que misturam o último nome tudo junto.

O nome *João Vasconcelos Neto da Silva* transforma-se em:

Sobrenome: Da Silva

Nome: Joao Vasconcelos Neto (sem acentuação)

Obviamente que a vasta maioria deles não tem certeza de como distinguir qual o sobrenome (nome de família) corretamente e por vezes pode ficar assim

Sobrenome: Silva

Nome: Joao Vasconcelos Neto Da

Sobrenome: Neto da Silva

Nome: Joao Vasconcelos

Isso fica estranho quando o nome é impresso num documento, carta, etc. Ficando algo como "*Da SilvaJoao Vasconcelos Neto*". Dependendo da combinação pode até gerar uma palavra ofensiva ou dependendo da cultura da pessoa, pode ser algo não muito aceitável. Pensando nisso, cria-se uma coluna que serve como flag para dizer que o nome é estrangeiro. Nesse caso o nome é impresso com espaçamento e até uma vírgula "*Da Silva, Joao Vasconcelos Neto*". Outros são mais sofisticados e imprimem o nome primeiro. "*Joao Vasconcelos Neto da Silva*". Isso depende muito da mentalidade da empresa. Empresas mais modernas com mentalidade globalizada costumam ter cuidados com detalhes como esse.

## Conflitos de documentos

É comum uma mesma pessoa ter o nome "desfigurado" em diferentes documentos. No passaporte, por normas internacionais é proibido suprimir qualquer parte do nome original, portanto o nome permanece completo.
Mas essa mesma pessoa abre uma conta num banco onde possui um padrão de 2 nomes e é inflexível, não aceitando nomes estrangeiros. Mas como norma os bancos precisam registrar exatamente como está o nome no registro de estrangeiro e, o registro de estrangeiro segue o mesmo padrão do passaporte. Nesse ponto começa a "lambança".

O banco vai registrar o nome mais ou menos dessa forma:

Sobrenome: Silva

Nome: Joao Vasconcelos Neto Da

E tiveram que se adaptar, aumentando o espaço das colunas no banco de dados pois não caberiam nomes com tantas letras.

Para complicar mais, não se esqueça que existe o furigana, pois eles precisam saber como pronunciar.

Se fizer um cartão de crédito, o padrão dos nomes num cartão de crédito é sempre 2 nomes e sem espaçamentos. Isso é uma norma inflexível na maioria das operadoras.

O exemplo do João ficaria impresso num cartão de crédito como:
 "SILVA JOAOVASCONCELOSNETODA"

<sub>Não existe acentuação no idioma deles, por isso removi os acentos</sub>

O conflito se dá quando essa pessoa precisa cadastrar-se em serviços onde o nome é autenticado mediante determinados documentos. Então a pessoa preenche o nome tal como está no passaporte e o nome como está no cartão de crédito. Isso gera conflito e fica até impedido de fazer um simples cadastro. Essa situação é comum em modelagens que não se adequam a globalização.

O um tema muito amplo e aqui só falei superficialmente. Como o foco não é específico do Japão, acho que até aqui é o suficiente para explanar as diferentes situações.

Poderia falar mais sobre o cuidado em não "descaracterizar" a pronúncia correta do nome de uma pessoa, mas tornaria a resposta extensa e muito localizada.

## Mudanças culturais

Na China, há também certas peculiariaddes. Ao contrário do que muitos imaginam, não possuem apenas 1 ou 2 nomes. As gerações atuais na China costumam adotar um nome em inglês, o qual é registrado oficialmente em suas carteiras de nascimento/identidade.

Tal como no Japão, possuem apenas nome e sobrenome, porém, adicionam um terceiro e até quarto nome em alfabeto romano, normalmente em inglês.

Exemplo: Chen Lee / Alfred Osbourne

O primeiro seria o nome em chinês "Chen Lee" e o segundo um nome em inglês que não quer dizer que seja a tradução do nome chinês. É meramente um segundo nome e sobrenome em inglês.

Não é difícil encontrar na China pessoas com nomes como Marcelo, Sheila, Sarah, Alex, Candy, etc, mas obviamente incorporado ao nome em ideogramas chineses, tal como no exemplo acima. A adoção de um nome em inglês é opcional no momento do registro de nascimento e serve para facilitar para quando viajam para outros países pois os nomes chineses são complicados para uma pessoa de outro país ler e pronunciar.

Normalmente os formulários em sites e sistemas em geral não pedem o nome em inglês de um chinês e sequer mostram tal opção. Isso é mais usado para documentos oficiais.

Citei casos como Japão e China porque é interessante ver que países "homogêneos" (sem muitas misturas de raça ou cultura) são mais globalizados do que países como Brasil que é inclusive um dos mais miscigenados/heterogêneos no mundo. Teoricamente, o Brasil deveria ser um dos países mais globalizados do mundo.

Comment: Excelente ponto a respeito de formatos localizados. +1!

Answer (score 11):

Diferentes culturas [tem diferentes conceitos de o que é um nome e sobre como escrever os nomes](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names.en.php). Em algumas culturas nem há sobrenome! A não ser que haja algum requerimento importante de armazenar o sobrenome separado você pode evitar bastante de dor de cabeça usando um campo único e bem liberal para o nome. Dessa forma o usuário tem mais liberdade para escolher como escrever seu nome e o sistema não pressupõe nenhuma regra.

Se a única razão para separar o nome em partes for para fins de apresentação (por example, escrever Sr. Silva ao invés do nome completo) uma alternativa possível em alguns casos é botar um campo separado para o próprio usuário preencher como ele prefere ser chamado.

Comment: O *link* é bem útil e o adendo sobre o tratamento também bem-vindo, mas não sei se a resposta em si é suficiente para apontar as vantagens e desvantagens. Parece que ela simplesmente está dizendo faça tudo junto, sem apontar porque.

Comment: fiz uma edição enfatizando que é uma questão de dar mais liberdade para o usuário.

Answer (score 3):

Reposta curta: em 2 ou mais colunas. Justificativa curta: para cumprir padrões.

---

Um pouco de história ajuda a contextualizar e entender a **relevância dos padrões**, e como se encaixam ou não a cada tipo de decisão de projeto.

No Brasil nunca é demais repetir, "**Existem padrões!**". Ao contrário de Portugal que tem a Europa para obrigar os portugueses a respeitarem padrões, o brasileiro é arredio à padronização: tanto os respingos da *colonização* no passado,  da *ditadura* da história recente, como da corrupção e burocracia generalizadas e ainda vigentes, criaram no imaginário coletivo brasileiro um [enorme preconceito contra padrões](https://medium.com/@peterkrauss/quanto-maior-a-centraliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-maior-a-demanda-por-governan%C3%A7a-democr%C3%A1tica-81ebd1a0ac88)... Respeito quem guarda mágoas, mas essa resposta requer que coloquemos isso de lado.

### Linha do tempo dos padrões

- **1986** - consolidou-se o padrão [vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) com a sua versão 2.1, por iniciativa de um consórcio de grandes empresas das indústrias de comunicação e computadores, incluindo Apple, AT&T, IBM e Siemens. 
  PS: o vCard é ainda hoje a referência mais forte no que se refere ao armazenamento e intercâmbio de dados pessoais.
- **~1987** - o padrão ISO 8859-1 (com nosso alfabeto e nossos acentos!) foi consolidado.
- **~1993** - o padrão UTF-8 foi criado.
- **1999** - primeira versão do *padrão RDF*, apoiado por  IBM, Microsoft, Netscape, Nokia, Reuters e diversas universidades.
- **~2001** - a [Web Semântica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_sem%C3%A2ntica) foi lançada como proposta, junto com RDF e outros padrões.
- **~2003** - "última chamada" dos comitês de padronização para substituir definitivamente ISO 8859-1 (e outros) por UTF-8.
- **2004** - surgem os  Padrões de Interoperabilidade em Governo Eletrônico (e-PING) no Brasil.
- **~2010** - o [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) passou a ser "padrão de fato", tendo ultrapassado ASCII e ISO 8859-1 juntos nas páginas Web.
- **2011** - surge o [Schema.org](https://schema.org/docs/schemas.html) como "padrão contínuo", apoiado pelo consórcio de Google, Yahoo, Microsoft, e Yandex, para suprir necessidades práticas da Web Semântica e acabar com a ["torre de babel" dos vocabulários básicos RDF](http://lov.okfn.org).
- **~2013** - a [Web Semântica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_sem%C3%A2ntica) "pegou".
- **2014** - RDF 1.1 consolidou a Web Semântica.
- ... Hoje Schema.org é um padrão de fato. Podemos usar direta ou indiretamente com RDF, RDFa, Microdata ou JSON-LD. 
  É onde veio parar o **vCard**. Os nomes próprios de pessoas físicas podem ser expressos com as propriedades `name`, `givenName`, `familyName`, `additionalName`, `honorificPrefix` e `honorificSuffix` de [Person](https://schema.org/Person). 
  A propriedade [name](https://schema.org/name), significa *full name*, mas é meio informal, e sempre pode ser construída pela concatenação das demais, via de regra sem os afixos.

### Sugestão de "respeito mínimo"

Armazene ou proporcione o armazenamento indireto de `name`, e, além disso, lembre-se que o formato também é relevante (não pode ser ASCII por exemplo). Idealmente tenha os demais campos previstos para *Person*... Mas aí vai também uma sugestão  de ordem de prioridade.

1. UTF-8: respeitemos o [ePING](http://eping.governoeletronico.gov.br/) e o resto do universo... O alfabeto do dicionário-`pt` é subconjunto, e nomes próprios podem ou não ir um pouco além (ex. Ångstron da unidade SI).
2. Tenha sempre como expressar o nome completa (*full name*) de **[Person](https://schema.org/Person) / [name](https://schema.org/name)**. 
    Não importa se foi armazenado assim, ou se há uma função  (ex. SQL VIEW) que **garante 100%** a recuperação do nome completo.
3. Nunca eliminar acentos: armazene num cache o `unnacent(nome)` ou use direto a função, não faz sentido "estragar para sempre" uma coisa tão preciosa quanto o nosso nome.

Outras dicas:

- Ter como recuperar ou normalizar o registro da "grafia bonita", com maiúsculas e minúsculas. Ver lembrete abaixo.
- Fazer uso de, no mínimo, [`givenName`](https://schema.org/givenName) para distinguir partes mais padronizadas (não é ISO mas [6,4% dos hab. BR se chamam *Maria*](http://censo2010.ibge.gov.br/nomes/#/search/response/495)) e poder, por ex., aplicar correção ortográfica. 
  O [`honorificSuffix`](https://schema.org/honorificSuffix) também é relevante pois requer grafia padronizada (ex. "Júnior" é preferível a "jr.") e não é o sobrenome.
- Na sequência, a propriedade mais importante da "quebra do nome", é   [`familyName`](https://schema.org/familyName).

---

#### Lembrete 1 - A normalização interna do nome

As convenções são mais ou menos consensuais para o português e podem ser expressas de forma mais universal como *regular expression*. 
Passo-a-passo da normalização de um nome completo (propriedade *name*) de pessoa física (classe *Person*) fornecido todo em maiúsculas:

1. Iniciais maíusculas, referido nas linguagens e frameworks como  `ToTitleCase(name)`, `InitCap(name)` e outros.
2. Por segurança um `trim()`  ou melhor ainda um *trim* depois de substituir todos os espaços múltiplos ou exóticos pelo espaço padrão singular, ou seja, a *regex* `/\s+/gu` por espaço.
3. Não nos esqueçamos do júnior, que a rigor precisa ser grafado também com inicial maiúscula e por extenso. Portanto: substituir `/ (?:jr\.?|j[uú]nior)$/i` por `" Júnior"`.
4. O "e" sozinho, substituir todos os `" E "` por `" e "`.
5. As demais preposições, `/ (d)([eao]|[ao]s) /gi` por `" d\2 "`.

PS: são as regras básicas e "consensuais".  Infelizmente é impossível sonhar em "abraçar o mundo", sobrenomes como "van der Waals" podem  ficar como "Van Der Waals", etc. no português.  
Cada projeto ou contexto de normalização decide se vai ou não arriscar a expansão das regras para "di", "dello", "della", "dalla", "dal", "del", "der", "em", "na", "no"", "nas", "nos", "van", "von", "y", e talvez outros. Normalizar suffixos romanos (I, II, III, etc.) também é interessante mas tem seus riscos.

#### Lembrete 2 - Vantagens

Os campos padronizados pela classe *Person* do SchemaOrg não são uma invenção "do nada", tem por trás uma história que vem desde o vCard.

A Web Semântica (ex. complementar seu HTML5 com Microdata) proporciona *dados abertos* e granularidade semântica na recuperação da informação. Não apenas o Google vai entender melhor, como qualquer outra ferramenta, simples [DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html) (sem milhões de dolares investidos em estatística) também vai entender melhor o seu nome, a sua página, o seu dado...

Em termos de registro de dados, o armazenamento da informação completa e padronizada garante não o funcionamento imediato do seu aplicativo, mas a *preservação de longo prazo* (vide por exemplo bancos de dados de sistemas de CRM, ou de dados oficiais) e a *interoperabilidade* com outros sistemas.

Answer (score 2):

Dando uma possível explicação mais simples.

Muitas pessoas possuem nomes compostos, exemplo: João Pedro Da Silva Machado.
Nesse caso o nome da pessoa é João Pedro e não apenas João. Essa divisão de Nome + Sobrenome facilita identificar o nome exato da pessoa. Essa não é a única maneira de contornar isso, como já foi dito nas respostas anteriores alguns cadastros também apresentam a opção da pessoa escolher como quer ser chamada. Enfim, eu entendo que quando a aplicação deseja apresentar uma maneira mais cordial e próxima de falar com o usuário, salvar o nome dele completo dificulta um pouco as coisas.

Answer (score -3):

Vai muito da necessidade do seu projeto, mas mesmo prefiro apenas em um campo nome.
Fica melhor para os buscadores pois você pode colocar sua tabela com prefixo e sufixos assim, ficaria. nome_sobrenome. Ajudaria na busca, no código, e deixaria o form mais limpo e fácil e atraente para dispositivos móveis. É o que eu acho, caso contrário me corrijam.