# Reescrita vs Melhoria Incremental?

Tags: php, gerenciamento-de-projetos, refatoração

No local onde trabalho atualmente estou implementando novas funcionalidades em um sistema legado. O sistema em questão foi escrito por volta de 2008.

Alguns problemas encontrados no sistema:

- Tabelas na base de dados com 90+ colunas
- Redundância de informação. (Dados duplicadas em algumas tabelas)
- Sem chaves referenciais nas tabelas (*Foreign Keys*)
- Ausência de alguns cadastros. Para listar para filtragem é dado um `select nome_campo` na tabela principal. (Os dados são inseridos apenas por importação de outro sistema)
- Falta de compatibilidade com outros navegadores. Só funciona no IE 7
- Sistema de permissão com arquitetura ruim. (É comum ver bugs em que um usuário ganha acesso a uma funcionalidade que não deveria)
- Tela principal do sistema possui ~1300 linhas de código PHP + HTML + JavaScript

Dado o cenário acima, é mais prudente continuar com as melhorias incrementais ou é melhor tentar convencer o cliente de uma reescrita?

Se a opção for ir para uma reescrita, quais argumentos posso utilizar para convencê-lo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sup>Tenho minhas dúvidas se esta pergunta deveria ficar aberta ou não. Dei o benefício da dúvida porque acho que uma boa resposta pode ajudar outras pessoas com isto apesar de correr o risco de me basear em opinião. Pelo menos vou deixar claro [o que é opinião e o que é minha experiência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101).</sup>

## O cliente vai pagar?

O cliente quer pagar por uma coisa ou outra? Ele quer saber dos benefícios de uma opção ou outra que no fundo não traz nada útil **diretamente** para ele. O benefício será mais seu e que pode refletir no que ele receberá, mas ele não consegue perceber isto, e não tem como provar para ele que um será melhor que o outro a não ser que faça os dois, meça-os e mostre para ele. Não preciso dizer como seria insano.

Pode parecer óbvio que um é mais caro que outro e dependendo de quem fala vai dizer que um deles é mais caro. Tenho minhas dúvidas.

Preciso dizer que cada caso é um caso? Preciso reforçar que **talvez** você [só terá certeza se fez o certo depois de fazer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)?

## Não reescreva!

O Joel Spolsky tem um [artigo famoso](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html) para nunca reescrever. O Joel é ótimo, ele era um dos responsáveis por um dos melhores produtos da Microsoft quando a Microsoft fazia produtos muito ruins. Ele é respeitado por quase todo mundo. Mas ele erra também. O Jeff Atwood já [o questionou](https://blog.codinghorror.com/has-joel-spolsky-jumped-the-shark/) antes e provavelmente este *site* existe por causa disto :)

Ele cita o exemplo do Netscape. Depois que deu tudo errado fica fácil dizer que eles não deveriam ter feito aquilo. Tem determinados softwares que realmente não deveriam ser reescritos, nunca!

Mas um software interno, principalmente um software que é um site, que tem problemas arquiteturais, será que não deveria?

Se pensar bem o Joel está certo. **Nunca, nunca mesmo reescreva um software do início**. Fazer isto está 100% errado! Se qualquer um que tenha experiência com desenvolvimento interpretar o texto corretamente verá que não há o que questionar.

## E fazer um novo software que atenda as mesmas necessidades?

Isso é outra coisa! Tentar reescrever um software que precisa ser compatível com o antigo sempre trará problemas e sempre custará bem mais caro. Ponto!

Fazer um novo que atenda as mesmas necessidades, possivelmente outras, sem preocupação com a compatibilidade é outra coisa.

A Microsoft reescreveu seu navegador (duas vezes, uma delas aproveitando o que já existia mas que não era dela). Não tudo, mas boa parte. Mas é outro navegador, não é reescrita do mesmo. O antigo ficará como legado. Quem precisar de compatibilidade ficará com o antigo. Quem quer melhoria vai para o novo (quase todo mundo). Ela reescreveu diversas tecnologias, como o Entity Framework e partes do .NET Core, criou um uma nova API (UWP) para o Windows, só para citar alguns exemplos. Não estou dizendo que sempre deveria fazer isso, principalmente ela porque deve atender a necessidade de muita gente e não algo específico.

Se fazer um software novo do zero fosse sempre ruim só existiria um de cada tipo no mercado. Às vezes precisamos concorrer com nós mesmos para não ficar de fora da concorrência.

Minha experiência mostra que tentar reescrever não é tão ruim assim, embora sempre vai custar mais caro. Mas já fiz isso algumas vezes de formas diferentes e as piores experiências foram quando além de reescrever, coisas novas foram adicionadas antes de reescrita terminar. Fazer as duas coisas não dá certo.

Por outro lado convencer alguém pagar por uma reescrita que não trará nenhum benefício direto imediato e só criará a base para melhorias é algo quase impossível. Já recebi promessas que isso aconteceria e o projeto parou no meio do caminho por falta de resultados imediatos.

Mas se você consegue fazer um novo software e consegue apresentar alguns resultados que podem aos poucos substituir o que está sendo usado tudo pode ser diferente.

Pode parecer que estou dizendo para fazer um novo software. Não é isto. Só você poderá saber o que é melhor. E se nunca fez não sabe se dará certo ou não. Mesmo que já tenha experiência ainda não saberá ao certo, só saberá minimizar os riscos.

Pessoalmente eu praticamente só trabalhei com software já escritos. E sempre que pude eu reescrevi, fiz um novo, não tentei nem de perto melhorar o existente. Fiz um novo sempre que pude, um novo sem preocupação com o legado. Deu trabalho sempre, me trouxe problemas, foi cansativo não só refazer mas também lidar com os usuários, mas nos casos que eu trabalhei era sempre possível fazer isso. E sempre que deu para fazer foi muito gratificante.

#### Meu caso

Alguns dirão que é mais profissional fazer o que o cliente quer. Eu pessoalmente só trabalho no que gosto, eu não trabalho no que me dá dinheiro. Dinheiro é consequência. Eu sei que nem todos podem fazer isso.

Eu sempre peguei software muito ruins, muito mesmo. Não só mal escritos, usando técnicas ruins e ultrapassadas, mas todos eles tinham problemas de arquitetura graves. A evolução era comprometida. Sempre peguei softwares cheio de efeitos colaterais que é um dos piores problemas que um software pode ter. Fazendo uma analogia com um carro, era comum que para mexer na seta se não empurrasse com um toque especial ele abria a porta. Não dá para trabalhar com software assim.

Já pedi demissão quando não pude arrumar essas coisas (fazendo um novo software). Mas é algo pessoal.

Nem tudo é preto no branco, as cosias são cinzas, fatores inesperados interferem., não somos robôs. Por trás de um profissional existe uma pessoa com características humanas e isto precisa ser levado em consideração.

## Qual é mais caro?

Eu não sei. Como eu disse antes, só dá para saber fazendo os dois. Mesmo assim tenho minhas dúvidas se dá para ter certeza. Se for feito de uma forma por uma equipe e depois da outra forma pela mesma equipe ela já estará mais experiente com o projeto e será mais fácil fazer o segundo, mesmo que isto seja feito incrementalmente. Se for feito por equipes diferentes, os resultados não são tão comparáveis, cada uma tem suas próprias características, computação é exata por si só, o projeto é humano igual qualquer projeto.

Muitos vão dizer que a reescrita é mais cara. Mas não se não tiver que se preocupar com a compatibilidade, se puder fazer uma arquitetura bem melhor, usar técnicas melhores, fazer de um jeito que você domine e sabe fazer bem mais rápido. Sai mais caro mesmo?

Eu **acho** que não. Mas não poderia afirmar nem que você me contratasse para dar um parecer e eu tivesse acesso a todo o projeto e que eu conhecesse bem a capacidade da equipe que fará o novo software.

É, a capacidade da equipe é importante, nem todos saberão fazer melhor.

Se refizer você pode aproveitar algo que já usou em outro projeto? Isso conta. Dificilmente você poderá aproveitar algo já feito em um projeto legado mas pode começar o projeto do zero com um esqueleto pronto baseado em um projeto seu já executado. Pode fazer uma diferença enorme. E pode ser um bom argumento para vender a ideia. Mesmo que você exagere na vantagem :)

Este projeto produzirá material que você poderá reaproveitar depois em outros projetos? Então talvez compense você subsidiar um pouco o custo dele, não repassar todo o custo da reescrita para este cliente.

Falo sempre em cliente porque estou acostumado com isso. No seu caso o custo se traduz em tempo. E provavelmente o risco é do "cliente" (seu empregador). Se não puder, dificulta um pouco mais o convencimento.

## Seu caso

Parece que você tem aí um software bem ruim. Isto ajuda a decidir. Não me parece, posso estar errado, que você precise manter compatibilidade. Você consegue ir entregando partes que demonstrem que há vantagens? Consegue mostrar logo no começo algumas coisas tangíveis, como funcionar em todos os navegadores, por exemplo? Pode ser alguma coisa simples. Consegue melhorar a usabilidade? Consegue colocar uma [*característica matadora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_feature)? Você tem certeza que poderá fazer algo realmente melhor? Tem experiência para isso?

Provavelmente o cliente demorará mais para começar pagar por alguma coisa, talvez ele só pague quando tiver tudo o que ele tinha. Você pode esperar? Se demorar muito, de quem é o risco de estouro do orçamento? Se for dele, certeza que ele pagará? Se for seu, você tem como arcar com isso?

Eu acho mais arriscado fazer um novo. Dificilmente terá um cliente que entenda bem as vantagens disto e tudo o que vai acontecer no processo. A chance do projeto parar no meio é relativamente grande (cada cliente impõe um grau de risco diferente e você provavelmente só saberá tarde demais).

É mais fácil "enrolar" o cliente fazendo melhorias em cima do existente. No longo prazo provavelmente sairá mais caro. Mas o cliente não perceberá. Vivemos em um mundo que o certo não importa, a percepção importa.

## Convencendo o cliente

Um vendedor profissional faria um trabalho melhor convencendo o cliente que ele deve optar pela reescrita.

Eu não sei como convencer um cliente, especialmente sem conhecê-lo. Eu acho que o maior argumento, apresentado pelo Gabriel Rodrigues, é que o novo software poderá ser usado por mais pessoas. Mas isto é argumento de vendedor. Nenhum problema. Melhorias incrementais podem conseguir a mesma coisa, e talvez consegue apresentar resultados antes. Então, eu como técnico não sei que argumentos posso usar a não ser que minha experiência mostra que no longo prazo reescrever pode sair mais barato em casos que o atual é muito ruim e que o novo não precisa ser compatível, só precisa resolver os mesmos problemas.

Outra forma de convencer, mostrada pelo Chambelix, é demonstrar que as tecnologias atuais estão ultrapassadas, têm problemas, etc. Talvez seja exagero mas é uma forma de argumentar com leigos. Sei lá até onde você pode ir com isso sem ultrapassar o limite da ética (se precisar exagerar nisso).

Tente se municiar de dados que mostrem as vantagens de fazer do jeito que acha melhor. Se você tiver dificuldade para consegui-los já é um alerta, mas não uma garantia, que pode ser que não seja tão vantajoso assim.

Mas tem uma forma ótima de convencer o cliente escolher o que você achar melhor. Dê um orçamento fechado com valores iguais. Nem que tenha que fazer um contrato de longo prazo com valores mensais mas não mostre que um pode ser mais vantajoso que o outro. Aí a escolha é sua. E o risco também. **Eu** faria isto. Reflita para entender o que é melhor para você.

Quer se arriscar? Dê garantia pessoal que ficará mais barato reescrever. Não sei se você tem essa credibilidade lá dentro mas é uma forma.

Uma outra forma: eu diria para mostrar o que outras pessoas experientes dizem. Eu diria para mostrar este *post*. Mas aí vão ler que não há garantias. Quem gerencia o projeto - mesmo que informalmente - não gosta de correr riscos e lendo isto aqui ele verá que há riscos, eu jamais diria que não, então não sei se ajudará.

Por último tente mostrar a diferença entre reescrever e fazer um novo, repensando, mostrando claramente todas as melhorias visíveis possíveis (as invisíveis é difícil vender) e como seria difícil alcançá-las com o código atual.

## Conclusão

Enfim, te dei alguns subsídios. É óbvio que a decisão é sua e você precisa estar preparado para tudo dar errado seja qual for a escolha.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: concordo com você em grau número e série, mas acredito que do mesmo modo que essa pergunta sua http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48666/14262 estava e esta dentro do escopo do SO-pt graças à tag `modelagem`, acredito que é o mesmo caso desta, por mais que seja baseada em opiniões, uma boa `gerenciamento-de-projetos` deve ter a analise de um ou mais especialistas no assunto. Portanto acredito que seja uma boa pergunta pertinente ao tema.

Comment: Embora eu ache inócuo, estou usando a oportunidade para mostrar que dá para emitir opinião sem tornar a resposta ruim. Se **todo mundo** fizesse isto, nem precisaríamos do motivo de fechamento para isto. Bom, precisaríamos porque tem pergunta que não ajuda também. Mas todo mundo soubesse fazer certo perguntas e respostas, não precisaríamos, Duh :)

Comment: Eu apaguei pois fiquei na dúvida se respondia ou não a pergunta, e eu tava sem tempo aquela hora para pensar melhor sobre o assunto. Eu acho que responde apenas parcialmente, vou ver se melhoro e restauro ela. Apesar que a sua já está muito boa.

Comment: @Math acho que a sua dá um bom complemento. Restaure, depois vc pode melhorar se quiser.

Comment: @Bacco blz, me convenceram :) Vou tentar melhorar depois, mas agora tenho que ir no dentista

Comment: @Math e se o dentista te convencer que você tem que usar uma dentadura? :)

Answer (score 4):

Eu trabalho em uma empresa de software para cobrança que usa um software escrito por volta de 2004 e estou desenvolvendo a nova versão.

> Empresas precisam saber de informações reais e de de experiências de
>   outras empresas sobre  o quão melhor foi gastar um bom tempo no
>   desenvolvimento de uma "nova" aplicação.

Vou te sugerir algumas métricas que você pode conseguir para explicar para o seu cliente, todas elas são baseados nos problemas atuais indiferente de qual escopo você aborda.

1. Alcançar mais clientes, esta métrica pode ser simplesmente explicado pela atual realidade do sistema que é ter compatibilidade apenas com IE7 e mostrar a possibilidade de fazer uma aplicação responsiva podendo ser acessada tanto de notebooks como também tablets,celulares e outros dispositivos.
2. Apresentar um tempo que o desenvolvedor gasta em media para resolver determinado problema com a versão atual e uma possível redução desse tempo adotando outra pratica, esse caso é facilmente visto pela quantidade de redundância no seu DB.
3. O item 2 também se aplica aqui, em adoção e melhoria no tempo do desenvolvedor para trabalhar, uma das boas praticas que adoto e ter um arquivo para cada, HTML,CSS E PHP, todos eles  bem organizados em um `Model-view-controller - MVC`.

O seu cliente quer com certeza que o sistema renda um bom lucro e que os clientes gostem, mostre que suas mudanças poderiam causar isto e você terá a aprovação para reescreve-lo.

Complementando o que o @bigdown cita:

> "Mas se você consegue fazer um novo software e consegue apresentar alguns resultados que podem aos poucos substituir o que está sendo usado tudo pode ser diferente."

Pensar em novos metodos para solucionar os mesmos  problemas que o teu software resolvia pode ser extremamente celestial, mas também pode ser um tiro no pé.

No estudo da interação das [Pessoas e Computadores](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_humano-computador) a abordagem de uma nova solução partindo de melhorias tanto de baixa camada tanto para a alta camada que é a visão do cliente.

Na camada Cliente tente melhorar a **usabilidade** do sistema. tem que ser fácil, simples é intuitivo usar.

Answer (score 2):

Como eu entendo a tua pergunta. Se o sistema é de 2008 isso quer dizer que foi desenvolvido com a realidade de 2006 para a frente. Mais ou menos.

Muita coisa mudou, muitas funções base do PHP estão e foram descontinuadas, pelo que se nenhuma actualização foi feita, isso vai ser sofrimento. A partir de Agosto de 2006 já estava disponível o PHP 4.4.4 pelo que mesmo assim depende se o servidor tem esta versão.

Sem falar no SQL reportando a técnicas de desenvolvimento e de manutenção de projeto e já agora até pela sua própria sanidade... pois também já passei por isso e sei bem o que é, não irá perder nada em colocar o seu ponto de vista.

***Na minha opinião é preferível partir do zero se é que tem orçamento para isso. Implementar um `MVC` decente e técnicas `Object-Oriented` eu não dispenso.***

**Alterar o projeto e colocar mais remendos pode inclusive colocar-te em questão enquanto profissional, pois à mínima... foi mexido por ti.**

Para uma empresa e para quem decide o que importa é menos custos e tempos de desenvolvimento para ontem... mas na vida real depressa e bem não à quem, sempre ouvi dizer.

Quando fala do IE7... penso que é fácil mostrar que a tecnologia hoje é outra e que hoje os browsers utilizados são totalmente diferentes na tecnologia que abraçam. O design centra-se muito em simplicidade e versatilidade de formatos, pelo que se apresentar uma solução que inove nestes campos certamente que quem decide vai olhar para a espectacularidade do resultado e lhe perguntará o que será necessário para o atingir.

Eu quando quero levar uma solução técnica em frente, mas quem tenho à minha frente não percebe muito bem a solução pois na verdade não é programador eu costumo elaborar uns layouts reais de forma a colocar na mão de quem decide a diferença e olha que resulta "quase" sempre.

Answer (score 2):

O cliente não sabe o que é uma reescrita. Você que tem que tomar a decisão e orçar um preço, daí vai do cliente aceitar o seu preço ou não, o que você está fazendo ou deixando de fazer não interessa pro cliente. O que interessa pra o cliente é o preço do produto, o resultado dentro do prazo e em muitos casos o preço da manutenção também. Você tem que garantir isso para ele.

Uma vez aconteceu comigo algo que pode lhe servir de analogia. Eu fui em uma concessionária para comprar um carro, daí eu vi o preço do carro e achei caríssimo, o vendedor tentou me explicar dizendo que o preço do carro estava muito bom e além do mais uma parte do carro era produzido em um cidade de um estado do Brasil, o motor era fabricado na Argentina, sei lá qual peça vinha sei lá de qual país, a montagem de tudo era feita em outro estado do Brasil ainda mais longe, e que no final das contas eu não ia pagar nada por toda essa logística! Olha só que vantajona? E ainda disse que se eu tivesse que pagar pelo frete de cada pecinha que se deslocou para cima e para baixo o preço do carro subiria ainda mais, então eu estava era saindo no lucro na verdade.

Depois que ele me explicou tudo isso eu perguntei: "E eu com isso?". No final das contas não fechamos negócio pois o carro estava muito muito caro, e pra mim tanto faz se as peças do meu carro já conhecem a América Latina inteira ou não.

Ou seja, o cliente não tem que ter todos os detalhes da implementação, ele quer o produto pronto e quer o mais barato possível. Se você vai trabalhar de madrugada e pagar mais caro na pizza que você vai comer pois nesse horário o motoboy cobra mais caro, o cliente não tem nada a ver com isso.

Em resumo, você tem que passar para o cliente o orçamento, o prazo e o preço da manutenção. Se você vai reescrever o seu sistema ou não é algo que você tem que **se convencer**, não ele.