# Modelagem de Dados

Tags: tipagem, modelagem

Boa Tarde Pessoal,
Estou estudando Modelagem de Dados e fiquei com dúvida com relação a como os dados devem ser especificados, por exemplo o que determina em um código se eu utilizo uma string ou um número inteiro para um Código de Departamento por exemplo? O Inicio e o Fim em valor de um Atributo? O Tamanho dele? Vachar(30)?

Muito Obrigada

Comment: Depende de uma série de coisas. Algumas perguntas ajudam com a experiência de quem já fez, por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48666/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121593/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53684/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57429/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108842/101

Comment: Esta pergunta é bastante complexa de se responder. Para entenderes deves conhecer um pouco sobre `tipagem dinâmica` e `alocação de memória`. Sugiro visitar os seguintes linques: [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135924/como-funciona-a-tipagem-din%C3%A2mica-em-python-3-x), [alocação de memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81046/aloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-mem%C3%B3ria-para-ponteiros)

Comment: Um aspecto da análise dos dados de seu modelo é determinar o domínio de valores de cada um dos dados existentes no modelo. A partir do domínio você determinará o tipo de dado que comporta os valores do domínio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na modelagem de dados, você deve imaginar quais os tipos de dados irá trabalhar.

Imagina um cadastro de usuários, onde teremos as seguintes informações:

- Nome Completo
- Data de Nascimento
- RG
- CPF
- Endereço
- Numero
- Complemento
- CEP
- Cidade
- Estado
- Usuário Ativo?

Como iremos armazenar estas informações? Em uma única tabela? São algumas perguntas que temos que pensar ao trabalhar com os dados.

Neste exemplo, um usuário poderá ter vários endereços (1 pra N), mas cada endereço pertence apenas a um usuário. Então podemos criar duas tabelas para armazenamento e relacioná-las, que seria `Usuario` e `Endereco`.

Agora para modelar as tabelas, **devemos pensar no tipo das informações que queremos guardar**. Exemplos:

- A data de nascimento tem letras? Não. Então será do tipo `date`
- O RG poderá ter letras e números? Sim. Então será `varchar`.
- Qual a quantidade de caracteres aproximada de um RG? 9. Poderá colocar um limite um pouco maior, pois não há um padrão nacional e cada estado pode tratar de uma forma.
- O CPF poderá ter letras e números? Não, apenas números. Então poderá armazenar como `bigint`
- O usuário ativo poderá ter outro dado além de SIM ou NÃO? Não. Então poderá utilizar o `bit` (0 = inativo e 1 = ativo).

No final, nossas tabelas ficarão assim:

**Usuario**

- Id `int`
- Nome Completo `varchar(50)`
- Data de Nascimento `date`
- RG `varchar(12)`
- CPF `bigint`
- Ativo `bit`

**Endereco**

- Id `int`
- Logradouro `varchar(50)`
- Numero `int`
- Complemento `varchar(50)`
- CEP `int`
- Cidade `varchar(30)`
- UF `varchar(2)`
- UsuarioId `int`

Neste exemplo, podemos notar que há um relacionamento da tabela **Endereco** com a tabela **Usuario** através da coluna `UsuarioId` e o tipo de dado é `int`, pois cada usuário terá seu código numérico único gerado automaticamente pelo sistema de banco de dados.

Para conhecer um pouco mais dos tipos de dados, dê uma olhada neste link:
https://www.rlsystem.com.br/tipos-dados-sql-server

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito Obrigada pela explicação Alex!